# Pipe one file to another

Tags: php

In PHP, is there a way to pipe or stream the contents of one "file" to another?

Here's what I'm doing now,

```
$rfp = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$wfp = fopen($this->file_path, 'x');

while(!feof($rfp)) {
    fwrite($wfp, fread($rfp, 1048576));
}

fclose($wfp);
fclose($rfp);
```

Which works fine, but it seems funny to read an arbitrary chunk from the input stream before writing it to the output stream. I'd imagine the file system or OS could do it a bit more efficiently if I could just tell it to read from one place and send it straight to another.

In Node you can 'pipe' one file stream to another. Is there a function for this in PHP?

Comment: `exec("cat file.txt >> file_copy.txt");`

Comment: why you don't use standard 'copy' function ? (http://pl1.php.net/copy)

Comment: You might be able to find other PHP commands (stream api?) to do basically the same thing, and possibly not looking so much like it's code from 1980, but I don't think PHP has anything like Node's .pipe(). p.s. I mean that as no insult against you or your code, but against PHP :-).

Comment: @AndrewLarsson: No. If you read the source I provided, the input file isn't a real file that exists on disk, but I do have a file pointer to it. It's a file that's being uploaded.

Comment: @ryrysz: Maybe.. I'm not sure if that will work with `php://input` or not, will have to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 copy("php://input", $this->file_path);
```

or second method:

```
 $objStream = fopen("php://input", "r");
 $dest = fopen($this->file_path, 'x');
 stream_copy_to_stream($objStream , $dest);
```